# How to play different audio fragments in js continuously like a stream?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, audio-streaming

I'm trying to create simple audio streamer. On js client i'm sending 1 second audio fragments via websocket. Python server returns this audio and it's played on client. The problem is the presence of gaps in the stream. What is the best way to manage this?

Frontend:

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8001'),
    audio = new Audio()

ws.onopen = () => {
    console.log('opened');
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false})
    .then(audioStream => {
        const mr = new MediaRecorder(audioStream)
        mr.ondataavailable = event => {ws.send(event.data)}
        stream(mr)
    })
}

function stream(mr) {mr.start();setTimeout(() => {mr.stop(); stream(mr)}, 1000)}
ws.onmessage = event => {audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.data);audio.play()}
ws.onclose = event => {console.log(`closed with code ${event.code}`)}
ws.onerror = () => {console.log('error')}
```

Backend:

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def handler(websocket):
    while True:
        try:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            await websocket.send(message)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break


async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(handler, "", 8001):  # listen at port 8001
        await asyncio.Future()                       # run forever

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I tried to create queue of audios but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this is to not use Web Sockets.  Have your Python server just return a normal HTTP stream and then the browser will handle all the buffer management for you.

```
const audio = new Audio('https://your-python-server.example.com/stream');
audio.play();
```